# is it possible to detect data drift based on the ground truth labels classes?

Tags: classification, unbalanced-classes, data-drift

i have 2 data frames, an old training data set, and a new training data set.
Both have the same features and order of the features used for training the model along with the ground truth column.
something like so:

```
f1          f2            f3            ...               Ground_Truth
v1          v2            v3            .                 actual_label1
v1          v2            v3            .                 actual_label2
v1          v2            v3            .                 actual_label3
.
.
```

and the problem is a binary classification task.
I want to know if I can do detect data drift based on the label of the data points.
Like for the 1s class, I want to see their drift calculations and for the 0s class the same thing.
I thought of just filtering the data to the class I want but I m not so sure about this.
Any suggestions, please?

Note: I have very imbalanced data, the majority class is way significant in terms of the number of observations with respect to the minority class.